# 7 Variables and 3 equations with perfect square coefficients, evaluation problem.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: How to solve???]

Here is the link if the image is not loading properly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pjm2.png

I'm having serious trouble solving this, the perfect square coefficients seem to hint at something. I don't know what its hinting at, exactly. Can anyone give me a nudge at this problem?

I tried on several other forums, but no one had a clue. I went to this one as a last resort knowing that everyone here is extremely educated and experienced at math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the three equations by $1$, $-3$, and $3$, respectively, and add them up.  The left hand side is the desired expression, and the right hand side is $1 - 3\cdot 12 + 3\cdot 123 = 334$.

What makes this work is:
$$n^2=3(n-1)^2-3(n-2)^2+1(n-3)^2.$$
To discover this third-order recurrence for $n^2$, write
$$n^2=a(n-1)^2+b(n-2)^2+c(n-3)^2,$$
expand the right hand side, and equate coefficients of powers of $n$, yielding:
\begin{align}
n^2: &&1 &= a+b+c \\
n^1: &&0 &= -2a-4b-6c \\
n^0: &&0 &= a+4b+9c
\end{align}
So $(a,b,c)=(3,-3,1)$.

Comment: Super good catch !